# Can I boot Windows 11 cloned with Clonezilla from USB stick

Tags: usb-flash-drive, windows-11, clonezilla

I have cloned Windows 11 ver. 22H2 (64-bit) installed initially on my HP Elitebook 840 G9 with Clonezilla. This notebook has NVMe with 512 GB capacity. Yet I use this notebook with Linux and have removed Windows installation.

In order to make UEFI/BIOS updates on this notebook I must replay a Windows installtion to do it.

My thought is that maybe I can replay image created from NVMe with Clonezilla to a USB stick (1 TB to be shure) and boot/use Windows from this USB stick.

Is that possible?

Comment: No, not possible. And a bootable USB stick with some FreeDOS or similar bootloader done with Rufus should be enough to boot once and update the firmware.

Comment: Try the Linux utilities described in the article [Flashing BIOS from Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Flashing_BIOS_from_Linux). If this fails, try [Creating a FreeDOS bootable USB stick to upgrade BIOS](https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/creating-freedos-bootable-usb-stick-to/). Let me know which one worked for you.

Comment: @harrymc - I didn't know or I forgot about the possibility of upgrading BIOS/UEFI from inside Linux with `fwupd`-tool. Now i have current bios UEFI: HP v: U76 Ver. 01.07.00 date: 03/23/2023 (installed from replayed Windows 11). When a new bios appears for my model I will try with your suggestions or with `fwupd`.

Comment: I have added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following programs can update the BIOS from Linux itself :

- fwupd
- BiosDisk
- Flashrom
- FreeDOS boot created by one of : Unetbootin, dosemu.

References :

- [Flashing BIOS from Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Flashing_BIOS_from_Linux)
- [Creating a FreeDOS bootable USB stick to upgrade BIOS](https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/creating-freedos-bootable-usb-stick-to/)

Comment: I was able update BIOS/UEFI firmware from commandline with `fwupd`-tool. Now I have `UEFI: HP v: U76 Ver. 01.08.01 date: 07/18/2023`.